# Line-Circle Interception (point,angle)

Tags: algorithm, math

Given **center S**, **radius r** and **angle alpha**, How can I find the coordinates of interceptions between Line-Circle (the line is given by a **point**(always center of the circle) and **angle**).The line is endless, so there are always 2 interceptions. It has to be a general formula/**code**. 
**The result are the coordinates.**

How can I do that?

Imagine rotating the line  angle =1 and getting all the points of a circle.

Circle-Line Intersection from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ did **not** work for me because my line is defined by a point and an angle.

[image]

**The solution I ended up with:**

x1 = centerx + R * cos(alpha)

y1 = centery + R * sin(alpha)

x2 = centerx - R * cos(alpha)

y2 = centery - R * sin(alpha)

Comment: This is more a math question than a code question. I'm pretty sure it's off-topic here. IMHO this question belongs to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) instead.

Comment: But, as a hint: A solution to this issue is to make use of the trigonometric ratios of a right-angled triangle to find the coordinates :)

Comment: x1 = centerx + R * cos(alpha) x2= centerx - R * cos(alpha) similar for y with sin

Comment: @Fareanor any useful pointer for OP to start?

Comment: @Miggo [1] "It has to be a general formula/code"  <--- formula 1st.. code later.. [2] " my line is defined by a point and an angle" <-- how is the line equation look like? [3] " center S, radius r " <--- how is the circle equation look like? [4] Solve the equation for line n circle.. we'll get the interception.. right? (pls share how far u get to.. or stuck at.. by editing the post)

Comment: @Fareanor sorry.. missed that.. /(-_-)

Comment: @Fareanor note that MathOverflow is for research-level mathematics, which this here certainly isn't. https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be better suited, but only after reading [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and formulating the question accordingly. As it stands, the question would likely get deleted there, too.

Comment: @MvG Oh right, I wasn't aware if this, thanks for the precision !

Comment: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/